# Поиск по тегам в разделе

Tags: search, php, mysql

Здравстуйте, мне надо сделать поиск по странице на сайте с помощью mysql.

Есть страница: audio.php и мне надо что бы по ней происходил поиск из базы данных. 
В базе имеется таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `audio` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `performer` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `audio` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `u` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `like` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Поиск надо делать по name и perfomer, типо как в вк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приблизительно так. Очень приблизительно:

```
 $name = *запрос*
    if ($result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `audio` where `name` = :name AND `performer` = :name")) // тут можно даже сократить запрос, но оставим для наглядности
    {
        $result->bindParam(":name",$$name,PDO::PARAM_STR)
        $result->execute();
        $assoc = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
    if ((empty($assoc['name']) or (empty($assoc['performer'])){
    echo 'Совпадений не найдено';
    }else{
    // Выводим, как Вашей душе угодно
    }
```

Приблизительно так можно сделать, но это очень грубый пример. 
Можно еще словарь синонимов задействовать, для более эффективного поиска.

Comment: @cnofss 

<form action = "" method = "post">
<p>Введите слово:</p>
<p><input type = "text" name = "name"></p>
<button type = "submit">Найти</button>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
// далее наш код
?>

Comment: Поправка:

    where `name` = :name AND `performer` = :name"

Тут определенно нужны LIKE, % и OR. Ну ладно, отсутствие LIKE еще можно перетерпеть.

Comment: @Etki ну пример же приблизительный дан был, всё остальное - за ТС Думаю, почитает, разберется, и сделает то, тчо нужно

Comment: Выдает ошибку в строке $result->execute(); . 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Comment: @cnofss точку с запятой на предшествующей строчке поставьте

Comment: А как вывести все это? Чтоб показывало напрмиер имя, типо такого $row[name];

И еще в строке есть ошибка

` if ($result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `audio` where `name` = :name AND `performer` = :name"))`

`Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

Comment: @cnofss $db должен быть проинициализированным объектом PDO. Вывод через `$assoc[ключ]`.

Comment: @Etki всм проницательным? Вы мне лучше напишите, как мне сделать правильно.

Comment: @cnofss,

> Вы мне лучше напишите, как мне сделать правильно.

действительно, что это я, это же моя работа, мне же за нее платят деньги, в конце концов \</irony\>

> всм проницательным?

![](http://media1.giphy.com/media/3i7zenReaUuI0/200_s.gif)

http://pastebin.com/nEZ9k8Di